# How can I trigger only the first function inside second function

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I have many elements, where some of them has two classes, and some only one.

**Shorten code:**

```
<input type="text" class="first second" value="" />
<input type="text" class="second" value="" />
<input type="text" class="first" value="" />
<input type="text" class="second" value="" />
<input type="text" class="first second" value="" />
<input type="text" class="first second" value="" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
var my_function = function() {
  // ...
};

$('.first').on('change', my_function);

$('.second').on('change', function() {
  // ...
  // here I want to trigger the above onchange function for the same element with class "first"
  // but "$(this).trigger('change');" will call both

  if (some_condition) {
    my_function(this); // <== here I get error "g.nodeName is undefined" in jQuery library
  }
});
```

How can I trigger only the first function inside of the second function?

Comment: You can put your first on change code inside a function and call that function.

Comment: No, that I can't, sometimes I don't need to call the first function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a function:

```
function f(obj) {
//stuf here
}
$('.first').on('change', function() {
  f($(this));
});

$('.second').on('change', function() {
  // ...other stuf here
 f($(this));
});
```

or use namespaces:

```
$('.first').on('change.first', function() {
  // ...
});

$('.second').on('change.second', function() {
  // ...
  // here I want to trigger the above onchange function for the same element with class "first"
  $(this).trigger('change.first');
});
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot this way of use :D Please, check my edit, I tried it, but I am getting error with `g.nodeName is undefined`. I know, I used it in different way, as you wrote, but I need it like this.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Josh Crozier is right, that I missed `call`, but this is the first solution, which also works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke the function with the same context, use the [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var my_function = function() {
  // ...
}

$('.first').on('change', my_function);

$('.second').on('change', function() {

  if (some_condition) {
    my_function.call(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. In my updated question the function `call` is missing. So at least +1, but the first and also correct solution is from madalin ivascu.